# How do I get an infinite list of powers using the below methods in haskell

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to do an infinite list of powers the same as I done them like below, for a list of fibonacci numbers and factorials.

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)

facs = 1 : zipWith (*) [1 ..] facs
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Generating the powers of a number is as simple as using 'iterate':

```
iterate (*2) 1
```

To find a specific power (instead of listing them) it is faster to use `(^)`.  To see the individual steps of a large multiplication you can use `scanl`:

```
scanl (*) 1 [2, 3, 5, 7]
```

Finally to generate a list of all squares this is the approach I recommend:

```
fix (\more r s -> s : more (r + 1) (s + 2*r + 1)) 0 0
```

Or if you are uncomfortable with `fix` here are two alternative versions:

```
unfoldr (\(r, s) -> Just (s, (r + 1, s + 2*r + 1))) (0, 0)

map snd . iterate (\(r, s) -> (r + 1, s + 2*r + 1)) $ (0, 0)
```

Comment: A solution with `scanl` would be `powers = scanl (*) 1 . repeat`.

Answer (score 4):

For greater readability you can also use `map`:

List of consecutive powers of 2:

```
λ> map (2^) [0..10]
[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024]
```

Consecutive squares:

```
λ> map (^2) [0..10]
[0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can define an infinite sequence of the squares with just a list comprehension:

```
powers = [ ii*ii | ii <- [1 ..]]

take 10 powers
=> [1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100]
```

Edit: It's been explained that you are after the powers of 2, which can also be done with a list comprehension:

```
powersOf2 = [ 2^ii | ii <- [0 ..]]
take 10 powersOf2
=> [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512]
```

You can extrapolate this to a generator function for any given base:

```
powersOfN nn = [ nn^ii | ii <- [0 ..]]

take 10 (powersOfN 3)
=> [1,3,9,27,81,243,729,2187,6561,19683]

take 10 (powersOfN 17)
=> [1,17,289,4913,83521,1419857,24137569,410338673,6975757441,118587876497]
```

Comment: Sorry yeah an example would be take 3 powers 2, so it would return the first 3 of powers of 2 -> 2 : 3 : 8

Comment: @lakers2012 you can always take a `tail`.

Answer (score 2):

```
powers n = 1 : map (n*) (powers n)
```

Comment: ... and then, `powers n = ps where ps = 1:map(*n)ps`, and `powers n = fix ((1:) . map (n*))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an infinite list of power N by **zipWith**, this may be an easy way:

```
powersOfN :: [Integer]
powersOfN
  = zipWith (^) [N,N..] [0,1..]
```

Here is an example of the power of 2:

```
Prelude> zipWith (^) [2,2..] [0,1..]
=>[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,65536,131072,262144,524288,1048576,2097152,4194304,8388608,16777216,33554432,67108864,134217728..]
```